# How to set x - y axis on ggplot grouped bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, axis, display

I'm having trouble making a grouped bar chart on ggplot.  I don't know how to set the y axis on the barplot.  I've tried with melt() function, yet couldn't do it.

The x axis is already set, now I need to set the variable "ab" as the y axis. Could anyone help me out?

Thanks a lot, much appreciated!

```
dataset
    ab  estadio manejo
1   2506    Huevos  mip
2   8616    Ninfas  mip
3   229 Adultos mip
4   2183    Ninfas3-5   mip
5   134 Ninfaspar   mip
6   1382    Huevos  nomip
7   3481    Ninfas  nomip
8   73  Adultos nomip
9   833 Ninfas3-5   nomip
10  na  Ninfaspar   nomip


> ggplot(mip,aes(x=estadio,fill=manejo, y=ab))+geom_bar(position="stack")+labs(title="MIP")
Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

*2nd time
> df1<-melt(mip,id="ab")
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped 

> ggplot(df1,aes(estadio,ab,fill=manejo)) + geom_bar(position="stack") + labs(title="MIP")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : objeto 'estadio' no encontrado
```

Comment: use `geom_col()` or `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to melt, your data are already in an appropriate format.

```
ggplot(mip, aes(estadio, ab)) + 
geom_col(aes(fill = manejo)) + 
labs(title = "MIP")
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate it @neilfws, great help!

Comment: Im still struggling with the y axis label. I cant add it to the plot, im not sure why.

    ggplot(mip,aes(Manejo,Abundancia), 
  horiz=TRUE)+labs(y="Abundancia")+scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,250,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,13000,14000,15000),labels("250","500","750","1000"))+geom_col(aes(fill=Estadio))
>

Comment: I think you need to remove the `labels(...)` from `scale_y_continuous`.